# How to run a string containing a static SQL query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function which generates a static SQL query and returns it as a string. What I need to do is to **run the returned string** as if I was typing it directly in psql. Here is a very simplified test case (the true mechanism is far more complicated but the following test case at least shows the idea)

```
drop table if exists person;
create table person(
    first_name  varchar(30),
    last_name   varchar(50),
    email       varchar(100)
);
insert into person(first_name, last_name, email) values 
    ('fname01', 'lname01', 'fname01.lname01@hotmail.com'),
    ('fname02', 'lname02', 'fname02.lname02@hotmail.com'),
    ('fname03', 'lname03', 'fname03.lname03@hotmail.com'),
    ('fname04', 'lname04', 'fname04.lname04@hotmail.com'),
    ('fname05', 'lname05', 'fname05.lname05@hotmail.com');
--
--
drop function if exists sql_gen;
create function sql_gen() returns text as
$fun$
begin
    return 'select * from person';
end;
$fun$
language plpgsql;
--
--
```

Now if I run the following:

```
select * from sql_gen();
       sql_gen
----------------------
 select * from person
(1 ligne)
```

This gives me the sql query. But what I want to do is to **run the query from
the returned string** as if I was writing manually `select * from person` in psql
and hitting Enter in order to obtain the result of the query.

I've checked PREPARE, EXECUTE on the online documentation but so far I've not been able to achieve this. Could you kindly make some clarification?

Comment: Show the true objective you are trying to achieve as update to your question.  If all you want to do is return a table then look at [Return table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And answer specific for `psql` is to change your semicolon to `\gexec`.

```
select * from sql_gen() \gexec
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Can the output be redirected to another query? For example redirect the above select  into a  CREATE VIEW AS SELECT . . .  statement so that I might be able to query the view later?

Comment: Found it!  select format('create view mytmp_v as %s', t1.colval) from (select sql_gen as colval from sql_gen()) as t1 \gexec